# python while loop non-exit

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

I'm writing a simple program and I just can't get out of this loop. What i want to do is if withdraw amount is greater than your balance, go to the while loop. The while loop should get a new input and check if new input is greater than balance, if it is repeat, if not go to the else, which is where i print the balance

```
class Account(object):
balance = 0
accountNumber = 0

def __init__(self, f, l, ssn, b):
    self.firstName = f
    self.lastName = l
    self.socialSecurity = ssn
    self.balance = b
    self.accountNumber = randint(0, 10000)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName + \
           "'s balance is $" + str(self.balance) + \
           ". Your account Number is " + str(self.accountNumber)

def deposit(self, amount):
    depositAmount = amount
    balance = self.balance + depositAmount

    print(str(depositAmount) + " has been deposited into account "
                               "#" + str(
        self.accountNumber) + " Your balance is "
                              "now " + str(balance))
    return self.balance

def withdraw(self, amount):
    withdrawAmount = amount
    balance = self.balance - withdrawAmount
    if float(withdrawAmount) > float(balance):
        while float(withdrawAmount) > float(balance):
            print("Insufficient Funds, Enter new amount")
            withdrawAmount = raw_input(">")
    else:
       print(str(withdrawAmount) + " has been taken out of account "
                                "#" + str(
        self.accountNumber) + " Your balance is "
                              "now " + str(balance))



testOne = Account("John", "Smith", "1111", 1000)
print(testOne)
print(testOne.accountNumber)
testOne.deposit(200)
testOne.withdraw(5000)
```

my problem is that i'm stuck in the while loop no matter what i put it says enter new amount

Comment: This is an indirect dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python ... Read that yo will understand

Comment: Is there a problem with my loop or my input?

Comment: what is the value of `balance`? Are you giving inputs like `100` or are you including other symbols? Can you give an example of an input and a value of `balance` with which the error is repeatable?

Comment: After all the edits i'm still stuck inside my while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kirk is right.

`raw_input()` produces strings, not numeric values. I suspect that `balance` was also created using `raw_input()`, is that so? If so, you are comparing string to a string, while you think you compare numbers. That is why you are stuck in this loop. Make sure you have the intended types of compared variables.

Try this:

```
if float(withdrawAmount) > float(balance):
        while float(withdrawAmount) > float(balance):
            print("Insufficient Funds, Enter new amount")
            withdrawAmount = raw_input(">")
else:
    print
```

If this works, I am probably right in my assumptions.

But I would advise to review your code before this fragment to make sure `balance` is actually an `int` or `float`, and also set `withdrawAmount` to `float` (or `int`) type at input (as Kirk suggests); this way you will be comparing numbers and all will work fine.

**EDIT:**

Ok I see a problem in your code. You actually subtract withdrawAmount from balance **before** you compare them. Try this:

```
def withdraw(self, amount):
     withdrawAmount = amount
     balance = self.balance
     while withdrawAmount > balance:
         print("Insufficient Funds, Enter new amount")
         withdrawAmount = int(raw_input(">"))
     balance = balance - withdrawAmount
     print(...)
```

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting stuck inside my while loop, even after your edits

Comment: Try inserting `print('Balance:', balance, 'withdrawAmount:', withdrawAmount`) inside your loop, and take a look at what are values of those variables. Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason Balance is printing out -4000, i don't know where that number is coming from because you can see balance started at 0, and in my test object his balance starts at 1000.

Comment: That's because you subtract `withdrawAmount` from `balance` before comparison. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for picking that error out. I guess I got a little too ahead of myself in the logic.

Comment: It works initially but, there still seems to be an error here, in testOne object i try to withdraw 5000 which draws the loop. then if i put 10 it goes through fine, but if i put 2000, then 10000, then 5, it would say insufficient funds to that 5.

Comment: I suggest to monitor variables using `print` again, it will help you see how they change with each input.

Comment: I fixed it, that my mistake, i had the balance = balance - withdraw in the while loop which caused it to change upon every input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79378/discussion-between-m-n-and-jumpman8947).

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input()` returns a string. You need to cast that to a `float` or `int`, like:

```
withdrawAmount = float(raw_input(">"))
```

Comment: I'm still stuck in the loop, it keeps asking me to enter new number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if withdrawAmount > balance:
    while withdrawAmount > balance:
        print "Insufficient Funds, Enter new amount"
        withdrawAmount = int(raw_input())
```

Which gives me this (balance = 50):

```
...
Try again
60
Try again
30
>>>
```

You don't need the else statement because the code will exit the block anyway after exiting the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
balance = 100
withdrawAmount = float(raw_input(">"))
while withdrawAmount > balance:
    withdrawAmount = float(raw_input("Insufficient Funds, Enter new amount: "))
print "Thank You"
```